# How to scrape all links from html table with net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper

Tags: scala, web-scraping

I am trying to extract all links from http table and after typing:

```
 doc >> elementList(".countries")
```

I have stopped at this html:

```
<tr class="countries" valign="top"> 
 <td nowrap> </td>
 <td nowrap>
  <a href="https://ar.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/ar.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://ar.indeed.com/">Argentina</a> <br> 
  <a href="https://au.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/au.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://au.indeed.com/">Australia</a> <br> 
  <a href="https://at.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/at.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://at.indeed.com/">Austria</a> <br> 
 </td> 
</tr>
```

now I want to get all links from that.
When I type:

```
 doc >> elementList(".countries") >> attr("href")("a")`
```

then I get only the first link:
`https://ar.indeed.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attrs` instead of `attr`:

```
doc >> elementList(".countries") >> attrs("href")("a")`
```